Optimizing Angular HTTP Interceptor for Refresh Token
I'm working on an Angular application with an HTTP interceptor for handling authentication tokens. I'm facing a couple of challenges and need guidance on best practices.
The interceptor currently checks if the request is a refresh token request using a separate function (isRefreshTokenRequest). I'd like to simplify the interceptor by removing this check. However, I realize that removing this check could potentially cause an infinite loop, as the refresh token request itself would trigger the interceptor. How can I handle this situation without explicitly checking for the refresh token endpoint?
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandlerFn, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, catchError, debounceTime, filter, Observable, switchMap, take, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import { AuthResponse } from '../interfaces/auth-response';

let isRefreshing = false;
const refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<string | null> = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);

export function authInterceptor(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);

  if (authService.accessToken()) {
    request = addToken(request, authService.accessToken()!);
  }

  if (isRefreshTokenRequest(request)) {
    return next(request);
  }

  function handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    if (!isRefreshing) {
      isRefreshing = true;
      refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((response: AuthResponse) => {
          isRefreshing = false;
          refreshTokenSubject.next(response.accessToken);
          return next(addToken(request, response.accessToken));
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          isRefreshing = false;
          if (
            error instanceof HttpErrorResponse &&
            error.status === 401 &&
            (error.error?.message === 'Token expired' || error.error?.message === 'Invalid token')
          ) {
            authService.logOut();
          }
          return throwError(() => error);
        }),
      );
    }
    return refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter((token) => token !== null),
      take(1),
      switchMap((token) => next(addToken(request, token!))),
    );
  }

  return next(request).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        return handle401Error(request, next);
      }
      return throwError(() => error);
    }),
  );
}

function addToken(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, token: string) {
  return request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
}

function isRefreshTokenRequest(request: HttpRequest<unknown>): boolean {
  return request.url.includes('/api/authentication/refresh-token');
}


this link was helpful

You need to use HttpBackend, where calls made through this are not intercepted by the interceptor, hence preventing the infinite loop.
From the docs:

A final HttpHandler which will dispatch the request via browser HTTP
APIs to a backend.
Interceptors sit between the HttpClient interface and the HttpBackend.
When injected, HttpBackend dispatches requests directly to the
backend, without going through the interceptor chain.

...
constructor(private httpBackend: HttpBackend) {}

refreshToken() {
     return this.httpBackend.get('route');
}
...

